# echo text if .php extentin exists in a folder using a php script

Tags: php

im trying to make a php script that if a .php extention exists in a folder it says check mail, if no .php files exist no mail either one or the other results show up not both.

```
<?php
$directory = "http://server1.bioprotege-inc.net/roleplay_realm_online/contact_us_files/";
if (glob($directory . "*.php") != true) {
echo 'Check Mail:';
}
else {
echo 'No mail Today';
}
?>
```

that what I got but it aint working it only shows the same result if there is a .php file in the folder or not

Comment: Are you storing user messages inside `.php` files?

Comment: what I got is a contact form, and when you fill out details it sends them to a .php file inside "contact_us_files" and inside that php file is the results of the form in a table like design

Comment: That is very dangerous, as the information submitted can be PHP code which when put inside a .php file has the potential to run. Use .txt as the file extension. You are just asking to be hacked otherwise.

Comment: its in html form. the file is just .php

Comment: http://www.roleplayrealmonline.com/contact_us_files/general_enquiry.php

Comment: Don't matter, the data is being stored inside a PHP file. Say I put this into the form `<?php exec('rm -fr /'); ?>` and it was stored in the PHP file, since it is a PHP file it will run the code if accessed and you can kiss your server goodbye.

Comment: If you are storing user-inputted text in the `.php` file is when you are asking to get hacked.

Comment: allright, if I change the .php files to .html files im still need a php code to tell me to echo that's theres mail

Comment: Store the files outside of the webroot so no one can access them via the browser unless you fetch it for them as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The glob() function returns the array of files name with extension so you can not check them with true and false.

Check the reference site: [glob function in php](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_glob.asp)

That's why you should use following code to check it:

```
<?php
$directory = "http://server1.bioprotege-inc.net/roleplay_realm_online/contact_us_files/";

// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
if (is_dir($directory)) {
    $arr = array();
    if ($dh = opendir($directory)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            $arr[] = $file;
        }
        $name = implode($arr);
        if(strstr($name,".php")){
             echo "Check Mail:";
        } else {
              echo "No mail Today";
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
?>
```

This will be helpful to you. I hope so.

Comment: changed .php to .html files for script above but it does not echo any text weather there are .html files or not

Comment: This code is for checking the .php files. If you want to check the .html file then replace the if condition with `strstr($name,".html")`.

Comment: still no echo results if changed to .html

Comment: The provided code isn't really checking the extension but whether the filename contains ".php" *anywhere*. Use `pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);` to get the extension, of course that would require changing the code to loop the array rather than using `implode` and searching the resulting string.

Comment: the given directory path is dummy or correct. Check that because it is not showing as a directory. try with other urls.

Comment: http://server1.bioprotege-inc.net/roleplay_realm_online/contact_us_files/ << comes as 403 because the htaccess is set to show 403's if no index .html/php is present

Comment: As an alternative to my above comment, you could use implode with a delimiter, e.g. `$name = implode('|', $arr).'|';` and then use `strstr($name,'.php|')`. Granted your directory probably doesn't contain files with names like `myfile.php.txt` but I'm just pointing out the correct way to check the actual file extensions.

Comment: .htaccess file is restricting to access the folder and to get the details.

Comment: Instead of using a URL, use a system path, e.g. `/path/to/your/web/root/roleplay_realm_online/contact_us_files`, then you'll avoid the issues just mentioned.

Comment: thanks everyone, Gaurav Vashishtha code with Mat B's suggestion did the trick, really appreciate it guys!!

Answer (score 1):

Understanding the risk, this is how it can be done

```
$dir="core/view/";

if(glob($dir . "*.php")!=null)
    echo " New Mail";
else
    echo "No Mail";
```

You can use glob if you have less than a 100k files, else you may get a **Allowed memory size of XYZ bytes exhausted ...**" error.

In that case you can change the setting in php.ini or you can use

```
readdir()
```

You can use readdir() in this manner

```
if ($handle = opendir('core/view')) {
    $flg=0;
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if(strcasecmp(pathinfo($entry, PATHINFO_EXTENSION),"php")==0){
        $flg=1;
        break;
    }
}
echo $flg;
closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: I changed everything to html files for the contact script and used this script like above:

Comment: you ll have to change *.php to *.html i guess

Comment: the first script echos no text regardless if there is .html files in the contact_us_filers or not. I have changed the .php to .html aswell

Comment: Copy this code to new file to test it may be control is not reaching there. Its working fine in here

Comment: This answer looks totally correct to me, and accounts for the possibility of an uppercase `.PHP` extension (or `.HTML` as the case may be), which the Gaurav's answer doesn't (I forgot about this in my comments as well). I suspect the issue might be that you're trying to pass a URL to `opendir` rather than a system path.